# AttributeError at / 'int' object has no attribute 'get', trying to get object id via for loop

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a project that'll display uptime based on an IP. The code is supposed to pull the IP from a model attribute, ping the IP address, and return either a 0 or a 1, which'll be passed to the HTML and checked for there.

I've ran the steps through in the python shell and got the data needed, but when running my test server, I get this error:

```
AttributeError at /
'int' object has no attribute 'get'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/
Django Version: 3.2.2
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'int' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Here's my code, if someone can help it's greatly appreciated!!!!

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import NewServer
import os

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    servers = NewServer.objects.order_by('id')
    #this should ping the server!!!!
    #loop through all NewServer objects, storing each
    #count in ids
    for ids in servers:
        #for every loop, set get_server to the
        #current NewServer objects via the id
        get_server = NewServer.objects.get(id=ids.id)
        #create the ping command with the ip
        #gotten through the 'ip' attribute
        #in the model
        ping = "ping -c 1 " + get_server.ip + " > /dev/null" 
        #store the whole command in the status_code variable
        status_code = os.system(ping)
        #each time status_code is ran, it should either return
        #a 0 (success), or 1 (failure)
        return status_code
    context = {'servers':servers, 'status_code': status_code} 
    return render(request, 'monitor/index.html', context)
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class NewServer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ip = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ip
        return self.name
```

index.html:

```
{% extends 'monitor/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<table>
    <tr>
        <th> Server Name: </th>
        <th> Status: </th> 
    </tr>
    {% for server in servers %}
        <tr>
        <td>{{server.name}}</td>    
        {% if status_code == 0  %}
            <td> Up</td>
        {% else %}
            <td> Down </td>
        {% endif %}
        </tr>
    {%empty%}
        <p> Hmm... there's no servers. </p>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: `for ids in servers` is already giving you all the server records one by one, right?  Can't you just say `get_server = ids.id`?  And you shouldn't be returning at the end of your `for` loop.  You need to accumulate all the results so you can return your dict at the end.  And two return statements in `NewServer.__str__` is wrong as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some changes will be required. You can put logic accordingly. The main reason you are getting this error is because you are returning just the `status_code` inside for loop. I changed it to something like this and it worked.

```
def index(request):
    servers = NewServer.objects.order_by('id')
    status_code = '201'
    context = {'servers':servers, 'status_code': status_code} 
    for ids in servers:
        get_server = NewServer.objects.get(id=ids.id)
        ping = "ping -c 1 " + get_server.ip + " > /dev/null" 
        status_code = os.system(ping)
        return render(request, 'home.html', context)
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

Thats not the correct logic which you need. But you can create logic to store each server and its status code in context. But the reason for sure is returning only `status_code` inside for loop.

Comment: That helped! Thanks! Now I'm just dealing with an issue where status_code is only returning the value of the last pinged IP, causing each site to display it's status based off that last IP pinged.